# How do you connect Wine (Linux/Debian) to a Windows Remote Desktop?

Tags: linux, windows, remote, wine, chrome-os

How do you create a remote connection from Wine/Linux to Windows OS? I had been wanting to connect to the Linux Environment on my Chromebook for some time. I want to try to play games on my Chromebook but built in keyboard is not ideal for that. I also wanted to see my Chromebook screen on my monitor. I do not own a USB-C connector so I want to connect to my Linux Environment from my Windows XP computer.

I know it is old and I plan to get a new computer in the future. For now, I want to be able to connect to Linux environment from Windows OS. My Linux OS in my virtual environment Debian 11 (Bullseye). I want to create a remote desktop connection from Windows OS to my Linux and vice versa. How do you connect it from Wine to any Windows OS from XP to 11 and vice versa? I am trying to figure out a way to do it but I am having trouble with it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include more details on what kind of trouble you exactly have when trying to connect from Wine to Windows: Which client are you using, what error do you get, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wine doesn't support Remote Desktop (as far as I know). But there are Remote Desktop clients for Linux.  Which I suspect will help you get what you want.

One of the more common ones is remmina https://remmina.org/